# How to extract html markup from plain texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have bunch of html data in plain texts that I got from CKEditor. It contains table structures and bunch of html markup.

I was wondering if there is a way to extract table structure and td data only.

The plain texts could be something like

```
first table....bunch more texts here...

<table>
   <tr><td>  data1  </td></tr>
   <tr><td>  data2  </td></tr>
   <tr><td>  data3  </td></tr>
</table>

end of table. test data here...

<table>
   <tr><td>  data4  </td></tr>
   <tr><td>  data5  </td></tr>
   <tr><td>  data6  </td></tr>
</table>

end of second table and bunch more texts....
```

I have tried

```
//tableData contains everything the user type in CKEditor.
var table = tableData.getElementsByTagName ('table');
```

but i just realized these texts are no in `dom`. They are just plain texts I extract from `CKEditor`.

How do I extract these `table` data?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to set `tableData`?

Comment: @jacob It really just plain texts I got from CKEditor.

var tableData = CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a `tableData` string from which you want to extract DOM nodes to be able to work on them.

To avoid parsing you can insert this string into temporary DOM element.

```
var temp = document.createElement( 'div' );
div.innerHTML = tableData;

// Retrieve all tables.
var tables = div.getElementsByTagName( 'table' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the following which pulls all of the tables into an array and then iterates over them.  Here is a fiddle that shows this in action as well http://jsfiddle.net/M5nMY/.  I am assuming here that tabledata is the id of the DOM element containing the tables.

```
var tableData = document.getElementById('tabledata');
var tables = tableData.getElementsByTagName('table');
var data = new Array();
for(var k = 0; k < tables.length; k++){
   var table = tables[k];
   for(var i=0; i< table.rows.length; i++){
      var row = table.rows[i].cells;
      for(var j=0; j < row.length; j++){
        data.push(row[j].innerHTML);
      }
   }
}
```

Note in this case, I have pushed all of the data from all of the tables into a single array one row at a time.